# Set position at random position on sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Small question. In my super small, 2d  game I spawn some enemies and I would like to position them in random position over the rectangle sprite. How I can approach it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide the code you had

Comment: There is no code to reviev. Only question is that if I Instantiate (enemyPrefab, position), how set position at random position over some sprite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the origin of your rectangle sprite:

```
Vector2 rectPos = myrectangle.transform.position;
```

get the half-width/height of your sprite:

```
float rectHeight = myrectangle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.extents.y;
float rectWidth = myrectangle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.extents.x;
```

get a random position within the bounds;

```
float xpos = rectPos + Random.Range(-rectWidth, rectWidth);
float ypos = rectPos + Random.Range(-rectHeight, rectHeight);
```

then set the instantiated objects position with these components:

```
enemyPrefab.transform.position = new Vector2(xpos, ypos);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!